# Checked for form errors; but now form fails to submit

Tags: jquery, html

The form stops from submitting to make error checks, but after the checks have been made; it won't submit.

I've made a [**fiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/kytCv/13/) to show you what I mean.

If you click 'Add' with empty inputs. The error shows as it should. But after you correct your mistakes and properly fill out the form. It fails to submit and never hits: `alert('submitted');`

my code: **(Updated!)** : [Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/kytCv/18/) Please take a look

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    required = ["id_name", "id_location", "id_start_date", "id_about"];
    emptyerror = "Please fill out this field.";
    $("#eventForm").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var errorText = '';
        for (i=0;i<required.length;i++) {
            var input = $('#'+required[i]);
            if ((input.val() == "") || (input.val() == emptyerror)) {
                input.addClass("tobefixed");
                input.css('border','2px solid #CF4046');
                input.val(emptyerror);
            } else {
                input.removeClass("tobefixed");
            }
        }
        if ($(":input").hasClass("tobefixed")) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true;
        }
    });
    $(":input").focus(function(){
        if ($(this).hasClass("tobefixed") ) {
            $(this).val("");
            $(this).removeClass("tobefixed");
            $(this).css('border', '2px solid rgb(187, 209, 236)');
        }
    });
});
```

How can I make the form submit? Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: what is errornotice here.?

Comment: code that follows a return statement will not be executed. `return false; alert("I will never be executed!"); document.body.innerHTML = "";`

Comment: once you e.preventDefault(), you must initiate the submit yourself once you have finished your validation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are returning if there are no validation message, comment your return true or place alert before return

```
 if ($(":input").hasClass("tobefixed")) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return true; // it goes back from here
        }
```

Apart from this you need to comment your last

> return false

Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HgEnS/)

You are placing

> e.preventDefault();

which is stopping the form submission though you dont have any validation error.

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5GEjm/)

Comment: PLease take a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HgEnS/1/. It doesn't actually submit.

Comment: +1 this at least addressed the problem that the OP has prevented the default action with e.preventDefault(); Honestly, he could probably just remove that line, and everything would work.

Answer (score 1):

Remove or comment `return false;` immediately above the alert. You are also forcing a return in the if/else above **that**.

Answer (score 1):

Code after return statement never executes.

```
  return false;
  alert('submitted'); // this never hits. Why is that?

should be 

alert('submitted'); // this  hits. 
  return false;
```

Update:

```
 if ($(":input").hasClass("tobefixed")) {
            return false;
         }  

        alert('submitted');
```

Comment: Please take a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HgEnS/1/. It doesn't actually submit.

Comment: your statement is true, but I do not think it addresses the problem. e.preventDefault() stops the submit.